# Update columns through SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a PHP script that upgrades his/her Firewall app (a function of my website). I have written this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbtest";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
$query = "UPDATE users SET firewall = firewall + 1, money = money - 300 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']")";
?>
```

Please help me and see what I did wrong.

Comment: You need to run your query with mysqli_query

Comment: i tried that but it was not working. can u give me the code?

Comment: Your're only declaring your query string, you need to execute it with `mysqli_query( $query )`

Comment: @Rainner thats not working i tried it

Comment: In the procedural way, [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) takes atleast two arguments, first is your connection handler and second is your query. So execute the query like this: `mysqli_query($conn, $query);`. And use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to get number of rows affected by this update operation.

Comment: A word to the wise: establish one account with SO and ask questions under it. Support those that answer. As opposed to asking, deleting, and abandoning accounts. Re: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET firewall = firewall + 1, money = money - 300 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
$update = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Comment: Thanks Bro u helped me @Adam Hull